# How to restore ColorNote notes after factory reset?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, backup, factory-reset, data-recovery, restore

I forgot to backup my notes before factory reset and now apparently I have lost them all. Before doing factory reset though, **Back up my data** option in **Settings >> Backup & Restore** was checked but right after it there was no sign of restoring data and such. I am not however sure if this has backed up any of my *ColorNote* app data.

There is a `backup` folder at this address `/storage/emulated/0/backup` which contains backup files for some applications including one file named `com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note` which should be related to *ColorNote* app. When I double click on this file, and install it, no note gets restored. I also did not have anything synced with my Google account before doing factory reset.

I know I have probably lost my notes, but still am desperately searching for some way to restore them! Those notes where stored on Androids file system, so my only hope for now is maybe I could use some file recovery application to recover those deleted files. Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated!

(Galaxy Nexus, Android version: 4.2.1, not rooted)

Comment: No promises, without paying a lot to a forensics expert I'd say "gone is gone" (as internal storage is not easily accessible to any recovery tools). But have you checked with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) and the questions linked from there?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the db files then the only way is to root your mobile and copy the corresponding db files to the location(data/data/com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note).

Comment: do you mean this address? `/data/data/`

Comment: Yes. And to view the files your ROM must be rooted.

Comment: In 2017, if you have the backup file, you dont need to root the device. Just install a file manager like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.filemanager&hl=en), copy the backup file to /data/colornote/backup (or similar path) in your phone and from the app go to Backup->Device->Select the backup that you just saved, to restore

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when I purchased a new phone. SD cards were not the same. One from my old phone would not fit the new one. I used windows to copy the ColorNote files over to the new phone.  I first used a USB cable on an old phone and copied files to a folder on the Windows desktop. Next, I used a USB cable on the new phone and copied the files into the Data/colornote directory on the new phone.

When I looked at the new directory there were no files but there was a backup directory. Seems that Colornote automatically backs itself up on your SD card unless you opt not to.

I used the Android software on the phone to restore the files to the new phone. I went to the ColorNote directory and found the backup feature. I chose the restore option and the latest backup file. After that procedure, all of my files were back again.

Answer (score 1):

> Your notes will be automatically backed up to SD card of your device, unless you turn off 'Auto backup' option. Also you can manually back up notes to SD card. Furthermore, if you sign up for online sync service, the notes will be backed up to the cloud storage as well.

**Source**: http://www.colornote.com/FAQ.html#collapse6

So you can check your SD card but that is about it.  If you set up cloud sync (which I think you didn't since you mentioned you did not back up)... checking your SD card is your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to mount your phone and use photorec tool in Ubuntu.
last time i did that to recover photos.. and it works (assuming factory reset is as equal as formatting the device)

Answer (score 0):

Next time sign in into Colournote Pad, you won't lose any notes. For now you can't do anything. I too lost my notes this way.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open ColorNote
2. Click on the top right for options
3. Click on Backup → Device
4. Pick an earlier time (there should be a list) and click on the box on the right. It showed me [9] in the box.

My notes were restored immediately.

Comment: By "*were back immediately*" I suppose you meant "were restored immediately", though I've doubts reserved considering the third point. Feel free to edit the answer to make the required correction if I I've ended up changing the intent.

Comment: So I had to do a factory reset and did the above 1) open color note
2) click on top right for option
3) click on back up device
4) pick an earlier TIME and click box on right NO EARLIER TIME WAS THERE AND NO NOTES WHERE RESTORED

Answer (score -1):

As I know: factory reset => erase all data. It is good to make a backup.. but sadly the backup is not working all the time and is not working for all applications. I'm sorry dude, you cannot recover your data. You could try at a GSM service... maybe some specialist can do something, but I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open ColorNote
2. Click on the top right for options
3. Click on Backup (spinning arrows) → Device
4. then just chose the latest date it was backup.

This should get all your notes back right away.