# I've rooted my Galaxy Nexus phone, but "/data/data" is empty

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-nexus, root-access, astro-file-manager

[As a follow up question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57782/how-to-restore-colornote-notes-after-factory-reset), I rooted my Galaxy Nexus phone using [Kingo](http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/download.htm), but when I tried to explore my phone using an application like ASTRO, I found out that the `/data/data` directory is empty. Why is it empty? Am I missing something? Where are application data stored?

Comment: Does Astro request SuperUser (root) permissions? If not, it cannot look inside those directories. You need the so-called "root explorer" feature, offered e.g. by [ES File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/es-file-explorer-file-manager/com.estrongs.android.pop).

Comment: @Izzy That should be it. Thank you! Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done, with some additional background information. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use "root powers", an app needs to explicitly request those from the system. To my knowledge, [Astro File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager-with-clouds/com.metago.astro) does not include this feature, but e.g. [ES File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/es-file-explorer-file-manager/com.estrongs.android.pop) does.

<sup>For most of the newer/updated apps, you can tell that by their permissions: if those include `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER`, they request "root powers". Alas: as this permission is not "mandatory" yet, its missing does not necessarily mean an app will not request root access.</sup>

The feature you need is called "root explorer". Mentioned *ES File Explorer* offers this, but you may have to manually enable it in its settings. That done, it should show you everything in the file system.

Comment: I could also explore the `/data/data` directory using `Terminal Emulator` installed from `F-Droid`.

Comment: `/data/data` itself is accessible to all apps, some of its sub-directories as well. But the apps' data folders below are not. Also: if the terminal emulator displayed a `#` as prompt, you've been in root mode, and thus have been able to access everything. You could have reached that by entering the `su` command, terminal emulator itself must not necessarily do that itself. If the promt showed a `$` instead, you've been in "user mode", and thus should only be able to see "open things".

Comment: You are right, before accessing the `/data/data` directory, I executed the `su` command.

Comment: Executing `su` in a terminal is "equivalent" to the terminal app requesting superuser, so that explains things :)