# Color note backup

Tags: restore

I am using android jelly bean 4.1.2. I took the backup of color note notes then i have formatted my mobile. Now when I try to restore what I already took a backup I couldn't find the backed up notes in color note restore option. The problem is that I couldn't find the backup data inside the color note application to restore it though I have it in my memory card.

Comment: Can you post the path with file name that you are looking for?
may be something like `/sdcard/colornote/backups/2013-12-8_back.xxx`

Comment: storage/sdcard/colornote/backups/

Comment: i have the backup where is specified above

Comment: But this is not been shown inside the color note application from which i can restore

Comment: So my assumption is that the path is empty. Have you tried searching the file on the entire `/sdcard` if you remember the name of the file or only a bit of it?

Comment: No i have all the files there in the specified path

Comment: Would seem to be closely related to [How to restore ColorNote notes after factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57782)

Comment: I downloaded colornote, made a backup on the sdcard and found they store two files for each back up(.dat & .idx). I found this on `/sdcard/data/colornote/backup/` , have a look at there.

Comment: ya i have those both files @ ironblossom.....Can i do anything with those files explicitely

Comment: Turns out .dat is for the password of the note and .idx is the note itself.What you get from `Setting>>Backup>>SDCard Backup` at the saved back up data?

Answer (score -1):

You have to go to the path `/sdcard/data/colornote/BACKUP/` and there should be the idx and dat files. If you have them and you want to backthem up, it asks for the password. I solved this problem by adding another android device.

- Take another android phone and install colornote
- Make a new note and save it
- Go to settings and turn off AUTO SYNC. Now you can backup manual
- It will ask you about a new master password ( type in 0000 or whatever)
- Now connect your android phone and copy the *whole* folder and paste it into the second device in the same colornote folder `/sdcard/data/colornote/backup/`
- Start colornote on the second device.
- If you go to backups, you will see the backup from your first device

The backup will work now and you can easily write it down or take pictures of your notes to put them back on your first device.

Comment: "U" is not a word. Please don't use txtspk here.